# How can I keep a PHP Session for 1 year or longer even though I close the browser window?

Tags: php, session

How can I stay logged in for 1 year even though I'm closing the browser window (using Sessions only)?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to keep a PHP $_SESSION for more than a year.
Here is the code you have to use on the page where the user is redirected to after logging in:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 31968000);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);

if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + 31968000, "/"); // 31968000 = a few days more than a year in seconds
}
```

Comment: Why do you set `session.gc_divisor` to 1?